# SQL Server 2014 enterprise slow performance with Apache, Php

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I have SQL server 2014 64bit Enterprise with 600,000 records running with Apache Server and Php5.
My problem is that, loading and processing of data is very slow even access is thru localhost.
Upon checking the process manager, i found out that SQL Service consumed at around 80-90% of the memory.By the way, I have 12Gb memory installed, and when i stopped SQL service memory suddenly drops to 5-15% usage. However. when i tried to execute query, select all, it just took around 40secs to 2mins to show all records which i think is fast enough compared to sql server 2012 below.

You guys experienced this problem? Maybe someone knows how to fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is using "select all" then 15,000 rows per second does not seem too shaby.

You may need to add some indexes to match the SQL your app is using.

Do not worry about high memory usage. This is perfectly normal behavior for an DBMS as it will cache as much data in buffers as it possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic but, I try to help.

Go on Sql Server and click on server instance with mouse right button. Choose properties and go in the tab "Memory" and check the max dimension of Sql Server memory as the follow image:

[image: Memory tab about server instance]

The screen shot is in italian but I've added a red arrow to sign the parameter you must change.

This feature can resolve the issue memory.